# Parse values of different type to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, parsing

I'm trying to parse certain columns into a date format and have had success doing so, but have run into an error due to inconsistency that lies in the data.

My date columns are currently integers in the form of YYYYMMDD, so I've used the following in the `select` statement to parse into dates:

```
CONVERT(datetime, CAST(date_column AS CHAR(8)), 112)
```

This works as expected, transforming my data into a YYYY-MM-DD format.

I run into the following error though:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

After looking through the data a bit, it turns out I have some cases of inconsistent data values, such as -1 and 10630 instead of the expected YYYYMMDD value.

Do I just need to add a `WHERE` statement to only apply `CONVERT` and `CAST` to YYYYMMDD fields while filtering out fields with bad data? If so, how would I do this, or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the note. Updated with sql-server tag - I'll be mindful of doing this in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume you are using SQL Server, based on the syntax of your SQL.  You shouldn't actually need the `112`.  `'YYYYMMDD'` is the default date format for SQL Server.

In any case, you can use `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
TRY_CONVERT(datetime, CAST(date_column AS CHAR(8)), 112)
```

This returns `NULL` if the value cannot be converted.  You can find the offending values using:

```
select date_column
from t
where try_convert(datetime, cast(date_column as char(8)) is null and
      date_column is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Parse() or Try_parse()

```
select parse('22-JAN-1989' as date)

select parse('04-March-1992' as date)

select parse('03/10/2020' as date)

select parse('07-05-1958' as date)

select parse('Aug 25,2016' as date)
```

Every example above returns a valid date.

You can also add USING 'en-US' or such if you want a different culture.

If you are getting numeric values, and you know the starting date, use

```
select IsNull(try_parse('16500' as date),dateadd(d,cast('16500' as int),'1/1/1980'))
```